# PHP Curl POST Problem Causing PHP to use 100% CPU

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to upload data with POST to my webserver but sometimes cURL just stalls and causes PHP to use 100% CPU indefinitely.

I'm using the code below.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$page = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Any insight to what is causing or how to track this issue would be great.

Comment: You're sure that's where it's hanging? For instance, can you print something before the curl_exec and after the curl_exec and never see the second print?

Comment: What kind of data are you POSTing? What does the receiving script to with the data? Which server is stalling, the sending or the ceceiving one?

Comment: I've ran that code around 15 times on my machine. The $page var is echoed just fine.

Comment: This randomly occurs, sometimes it works and sometimes this happens. I'm uploading files via post to my webserver via another server. The issue occurs on the server that is running the script to upload

After uploading all the script do is check to see if was successful. When this problem occurs I notice using CURL_VERBOSE option that it didn't check if the file upload correctly or not so I'm guessing this is where it happens. I'm running the script via cron every 10 minutes and most of the time it works but when this happens a PHP process eats 100% CPU and stays there until I kill the process

Answer (score 1):

If it really is the actual curl "call" that hangs and performs 100% CPU, then that is a curl bug and you should probably consider upgrading your libcurl.

Comment: Is there a way to update libcurl without recompiling PHP? I'm using Yum to install so compiling from source would mess everything else up.

Comment: 7.12.1 is truly ANCIENT so you really should upgrade that. And you should be able to upgrade without recompiling, but that's a completely different topic...

Answer (score 0):

Can you determine if it's related to a specific file? Perhaps there's something related to encoding, or upload length?

My first thought would be to at least determine if a specific file/set of files are causing the problem; write out the filenames (and perhaps content) and types before the upload, and the filename after it completes. That way you'll know exactly which files are causing the problem, and you can move on from there.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is with what you're specifying as the post data. Could you do a `var_dump($postdata)` right before your call to cURL and post the output here? cURL could be getting hung up on a typecasting/serialization issue, or your post data is simply invalid (and hopefully we can correct it!).

Answer (score -2):

Upgrade to the newest version of PHP, PHP 5.3.1.

If the problem still persists, and your server is running Windows, upgrade it to anything else, particularily a form of *NIX: a GNU/Linux distribution, a form of BSD, SunOS, etc...

If the problem persists even then, or you think Windows is a good OS for servers [1], the instructions to track the problem and send a bug report are over here: http://bugs.php.net/how-to-report.php

[1] Microsoft itself has to restart each machine behind microsoft.com every month.

Comment: Ditching your OS because of a random CPU usage issue is a crazy idea. PHP runs fine on Windows, as many people can attest.

Comment: Downvoting an answer which contains the answer to his question is not good karma either :P

What I practically did was to tell him where the "bug" might be, how to fix it, and/or how to report it

Comment: This is nonsense. Windows is not my first choice for a server OS either, but I there are numerous perfectly fine production PHP sites hosted on Windows without any problems. Suggesting to "upgrade" to a *nix because of an unidentified bug is daft.

Comment: I am suggesting trying the code on another OS in order to identify the source of the bug: is it because of a windows-specific part in PHP, or is it general? Does it behave the same in the latest version of PHP? If so, which OSes. These are all questions to ask yourself when creating a bug report.

Comment: I've just upgraded to the lastest PHP and the problem still exist. I have strace the process and getting this as a reponse:

poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT, revents=POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 0) = 1
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT, revents=POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1000) = 1
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT, revents=POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 0) = 1
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT, revents=POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1000) = 1
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT, revents=POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 0) = 1
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT, revents=POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1000) = 1

Comment: Can you test it on a remote *NIX as well? As you were told, for others and for myself your code works. What OS/version are you using? Try compiling it with debug info as described in the link above, and submit a bug report.

Comment: The server I'm testing the codes on are CentOS 4.x, the issue is indeed with CURL I believe, I went through the code and echo out the output before and after every CURL call and it stops after the CURL. I'm using Curl Version curl 7.12.1.